# LLNCS bibliography problem

Tags: lncs

I am using llncs format to write a paper. But I am not getting the references as mentioned in the sample pdf file. All my references as stored in one bib file. Can some one tell me what are exact commands I should use to get llncs reference style.
Thank you.

Comment: In addition to having `\documentclass{llncs}` be the opening instruction of the document, do you have the directive `\bibliographystyle{splncs03}` somewhere in the document, and did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? If you've done all these things and no bibliography is generated, have you checked the `xxx.log` and `xxx.blg` files (where `xxx` is the name of your main tex file) for error messages?

Comment: Does llncs format gives references in numeric format or some thing like[ABC10]. Can some tell me exact order of references.

Comment: Unless you use a specialized citation management package such as `natbib`, it is the bibliography style (for your document, probably `splncs03`) and not the document class (`llncs`) that determines the format of the citation callouts and the sorting order (or lack thereof) of the entries in the bibliography. With `splncs03`, the citation callouts will be numeric and the bibliographic references will be sorted alphabetically by authors' names.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for help. Now every thing is working fine

Comment: @Mico Either an answer or vote for closing.

Comment: @egreg -- Done. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the bibliography style that is to be applied -- the document class `llncs` doesn't do that for you.

Springer distributes the style file `splncs03.bst` along with the document class file `llncs.cls`. Your preamble should therefore contain the following instructions

```
\documentclass{llncs} 
...
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
...
```

Whenever the argument of `\bibliographystyle` is modified, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: The files are available at ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/. A minimal LNCS template with some enhancements is available at https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS

Answer (score 3):

FIXED!
Add these lines to end of your tex file...

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\bibliography{bibfilename}
```

Run commands: BIBTEX, and PDFLatex (if applicable) and the references should appear.

I hope it helps?